# Will this use of threads in Android be infinite

Tags: android, concurrency

I have a card game in which play passes automatically from player to play. There are 3 non-user players and play flows from one to the next without user intervention every number of seconds (as specified by the user).

I have 2 methods that control the flow:

1. awaitTurn which is used to wait for the start of the turn
2. doTurn when the actual turn starts

They are both within the same class.
Each player has their own instance of the class.

After the player has finished its turn it then invokes the "awaitTurn()" of the next player and so on.

After the 3 automated player makes its turn then control is sent to the "awaitTurn()" of the user which effectively does nothing and allows the user to make his/her turn.

In order to pause I wrote the following code:

```
public void awaitTurn()
{
    GameActivity.thisActivity.displayHideCont(View.VISIBLE);
    if (GameActivity.settings.getPauseTimeBetweenTurns() > 0){
        startNextPlayerTurn = new Runnable() {public void run() {doTurn();}};

        if (handler == null)
            handler = new Handler();
        else
            handler.removeCallbacks(startNextPlayerTurn);

        int extraDelay = GameActivity.settings.getCardAnimationTime();

        handler.postDelayed(startNextPlayerTurn, 
                            (GameActivity.settings.getPauseTimeBetweenTurns())*1000 + extraDelay);
    }

    return;
}
```

In `doTurn` I have:

```
public void doTurn() {    
        if (startNextPlayerTurn!=null)  // just in case we are still pausing
            handler.removeCallbacks(startNextPlayerTurn);
    ...
}
```

So, the big question is, whether I am building here an infinite depth of threads one from within the other or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not create threads in your application. You run all functions in your main UI thread (assuming handler is created in UI thread).

Here is what happens:

1. The call to `handler.postDelayed(runnableX, delayX)` puts `runnableX` into UI queue and will be processed after `delayX`.
2. When time comes, UI thread's loop takes `runnableX` and runs it.

If you call `handler.removeCallbacks(runnableX)`, then all pending messages with `runnableX` are removed from queue (and will not run).

If you do multiple calls to `handler.postDelayes(runnableX, delayX)`, then your `runnableX` will be called multiple times. But each time it will be run on UI thread.

Unfortunately there is no way to check whether your `runnableX` is already posted to queue.

Comment: It's not possible for an extra postDelay to happen before a removeCallbacks happens.

Comment: Is this a question? Or a statement about your code? Or a statement about Handler? Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Statement. There is no way in the logic of the program that it can reach the postDelayed a second time without reaching the removeAllCallbacks. My main question was whether the postDelayed posted a new thread each time one within the other.

Comment: Ok, I got it. The answer is - no, everything runs in one main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think I wouldn't have a player invoke a method of another player, I'd have some type of "player manager" tell a player when it's its turn, and, if necessary, have the player tell the manager when it's finished its turn.